# Docker 'exitpoint' - run a command before a container is `down`ed or `stop`ped?

Tags: linux, shell, docker

Why? Because I'm [propagating binds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation) to allow a container to mount a union filesystem, and when it exits it leaves its mess behind. `fusermount -uz /mount/point` cleans it up, so I want that to happen on exit.

---

Is there any way of providing something like an exit-point or exit command for a Docker container?

I've tried appending `; echo EXITING ; myexitcmd` to the entrypoint, the existing command being long-running, but it seems not to run.

This entirely makes sense, since what's running is `sh -c "myentrycmd; echo EXITING; myexitcmd"`, and it's that shell that's getting killed, not `myentrycmd` within it.

So a solution need not be Docker-specific, I could alternatively phrase my question: How can I catch all 'exit' signals, and finish running my (inline) script first/instead?

I've also tried as an entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
cleanup() {
    echo EXITING
    myexitcmd
}

trap 'cleanup' INT
myentrycmd
```

with `STOPSIGNAL SIGINT` in the Dockerfile. No cigars there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [minit](https://github.com/chazomaticus/minit) as an entrypoint.  It runs /etc/minit/startup on container startup and /etc/minit/shutdown when a container is stopped.